# jstree icons missing in print

Tags: printing, icons, themes, jstree

I have a webpage using jstree. It displays what I wanted perfectly. but when I print the page the jstree icons missing in the print.

Any idea why this happens?

I tried with most of the possible css settings.

The code I used is here. and below are the images 1. Display and 2. Print.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Tree').jstree({ "themes": {
        "theme": "apple"
    },
        "plugins": ["themes", "html_data"]
    });
    $.jstree._themes = GetThemePath() + "jsTree/themes/";
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't attach the images.

Comment: Which browser and what plugin to print?

Comment: Its IE9 and just File--> Print

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a plugin to print:
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-print-page-options/

I've used jqPrint successfully in the past.

Comment: What did you try? What did you see?